# Resizable Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, components

I am looking for a component that resembles to Google Finance resizable scrollbar.
Here is the link:
http://www.google.com/finance?q=EURUSD&ei=bhM_UKDXF-aIwAPVNQ
you can find it below the chart.
Does any one know where I can find a similar component?

Thank you.

Comment: Its made with ActionScript, not javascript. Just right-click it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think [amcharts.com](http://amcharts.com) does it too. Check the site once.

Answer (score 0):

I found the a nice component in D3 framework.
It is called Swimlane Chart and can be found on:

http://bl.ocks.org/1962173

Thank you.